# How to use multiple resource url in botframework oauth?

Tags: botframework

I followed below article to add authentication to my azure bot. Everything works fine, except below step:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript#azure-ad-v1

Register your Azure AD application with your bot, step g, to add Resource URL

In my case, I need to grant bot permission to access both powerbi and sharepoint API, according to the document they are in two different domain, https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/ and https://mytanent.sharepoint.com

But this field in bot setting page can only accept one URL.

Anyone can help on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use [AADv2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication#azure-ad-v2), which requires no resource URL. If you use AADv1 then you can probably still use `https://graph.microsoft.com/` as your resource URL, but if that doesn't work then you might try just using your app registration's client ID as the resource URL. The place where you'll want to configure Power BI and SharePoint permissions is described in [Create your Azure AD application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication#create-your-azure-ad-application) 6c:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestions, but none of them work for my case.

I've tried the AADv2 previously, it will return AADSTS650053: The application 'xxx' asked for scope 'Report.Read.All' that doesn't exist on the resource 'xxxxx', even the scope permission is already added to the app.

Comment: And using the client ID as resource URL will get 'The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx'. This happened because application is misconfigured: it must require access to Windows Azure Active Directory by specifying at least 'Sign in and read user profile' permission.

I'll contact our admin to add User.Read.All permission to the application and try again.

Comment: @BerryTian - Did you try again?